# Como utilizar componentes Windows Forms em uma aplicação WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, wpf

Existe alguma forma de utilizar os componentes do Windows Forms no WPF? Por exemplo, eu preciso usar o controle `Chart` ou o `MaskedTextBox` do Windows Forms, que não existe em aplicações WPF, como eu poderia utilizá-lo no meu aplicativo WPF?

Deixo mais algumas perguntas sobre o mesmo:

- Existem desvantagens ao utilizar componentes WF no WPF?
- É mais vantajoso criar um componente WPF do que usar o já existente
  no WF?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Existe alguma forma de utilizar os componentes do Windows Forms no WPF?

[Sim](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751797(v=vs.110).aspx), desde que adicione ao projecto referências aos seguintes *assemblies*:

- System.Windows.Forms
- [WindowsFormsIntegration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration(v=vs.110).aspx)

Para os utilizar use um *WindowsFormsHost* e adicione os componentes como filhos.

Exemplo para o `MaskedTextBox`:

```
<Window x:Class="TesteWpf.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:wf="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <WindowsFormsHost>
            <wf:MaskedTextBox Mask="00/00/0000">

            </wf:MaskedTextBox>

        </WindowsFormsHost>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Exemplo para o `Chart`:

Adicione uma referência ao *assembly* System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="TesteWpf.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:winformchart="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>

        <WindowsFormsHost>
            <winformchart:Chart x:Name="Chart" Dock="Fill">
                <winformchart:Chart.Series>
                    <winformchart:Series Name="series" ChartType="Line"/>
                </winformchart:Chart.Series>
                <winformchart:Chart.ChartAreas>
                    <winformchart:ChartArea/>
                </winformchart:Chart.ChartAreas>
            </winformchart:Chart>
        </WindowsFormsHost>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;

namespace TesteWpf
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var graphicValues = new Dictionary<int, double>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                graphicValues.Add(i, 10 * i);
            }

            Chart.DataSource = graphicValues;
            Chart.Series["series"].XValueMember = "Key";
            Chart.Series["series"].YValueMembers = "Value";
        }
    }
}
```

> Existem desvantagens ao utilizar componentes WF no WPF?

- Mistura de tecnologias, existem algumas [questões a ter em conta](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/scoberry/2006/09/01/gotchas-for-working-with-windows-formswpf-interop/), umas simplesmente porque as duas tecnologias não vêm juntas sem problemas, outras porque são ou decisões de design ou diferenças de concepção entre Windows Forms e WPF.

> É mais vantajoso criar um componente WPF do que usar o já existente no WF.

- Pelas razões acima indicadas.
- Se tiver disponibilidade e engenho para o criar.

Comment: boa resposta...

Answer (score 2):

**XAML**

```
<Grid Name="grid1">

</Grid>
```

**Code Behind**

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{
    // Cria um host para windows forms
    System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost host =
        new System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost();

    // cria o componente de máscara do windows forms
    MaskedTextBox mtbDate = new MaskedTextBox("00/00/0000");

    // adiciona o MaskedTextBox no host
    host.Child = mtbDate;

    // adiciona o host na grid do WPF
    this.grid1.Children.Add(host);
}
```

Precisa adicionar

```
  using System.Windows.Forms;
```

**Fonte**: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms751761(v=vs.110).aspx

**Meu exemplo prático**

Eu já usei o Windows Forms Host para utilizar ReportViewer no WPF

```
<mah:MetroWindow x:Class="Capacitor.WPF.View.Relatorios.TelaRelatorio"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:mah="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
        xmlns:view="clr-namespace:Capacitor.WPF.View"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:rv="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms;assembly=Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms"
        BorderBrush="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}"
        Title="Relatório" Height="1101.88" Width="814.286" WindowState="Maximized">
    <Grid>
        <WindowsFormsHost>
            <rv:ReportViewer x:Name="reportViewer"/>
        </WindowsFormsHost>
    </Grid>
</mah:MetroWindow>
```

Eu recomendo criar um controlle de máscara em WPF mesmo, tem muitos exemplos na internet, pra evitar dependências com Windows Forms. Por exemplo, se você utilizar uma estilização com Styles no WPF, muito provavelmente não vai conseguir aplicar esses estilos nesses caras.

Mas eu como precisava usar o ReportViewer, eu tive que apelar para o WindowsFormsHost. Porém eu senti que ficou mais lento essa tela.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Mas por que deveríamos evitar dependências com o WF?

Comment: Por exemplo, se você utilizar uma estilização com Styles no WPF, muito provavelmente não vai conseguir aplicar esses estilos nesses caras.